# how to use strings.xml file in a service?

Tags: android, service

I have a service in my app and I what to access to the strings.xml file that contain what I need.

I want to get a string that are in the strings.xml but I can't acces to this file in my service.

I think that the problem deals with the context but I can't resolve it.

There is an extract of my service:

```
package com.receiver;

protected Void doInBackground() {

    // GPS timeout
    final int maxSeconds = 60; //30
    int count = 0;

    // If we've finished finding location or exceeded timeout,
    // break the loop.
    while (findingLocation && count < maxSeconds) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // Continue if interrupted
        }
        // Increment the timer by one second
        count++;
    }

    // If we're still finding location, switch to network locations.
    if (findingLocation) {
        locationHandler.sendMessage(new Message());
        locationManager.removeUpdates(SMSReceiver.this);
        lat = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER).getLatitude();
        lng = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER).getLongitude();
        msg = "";// here I whant to get my string from the strings.xml but I can't access to this file
    } else {
        lat = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER).getLatitude();
        lng = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER).getLongitude();
        msg = " "; // here I whant to get other string from the strings.xml but I can't access to this file
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you taking about and Android service? From you code snippet it looks like you want to access a string from an AsyncTask.

For a regular Android service, you can use the `getString()` method from `Context` since a `Service` extends `Context`. Simply pass in the resource ID of the string you want, and you should be all set.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString(int)

In order to access the string from an `AsyncTask`, I usually just pass the ApplicationContext to the `AsyncTask`, then I can access anything I want. Keep in mind that passing around Contexts can be problematic so, you might want to pass the actual string to the `AsyncTask` so it does not need a `Context` reference.